# problem with "-" sign in equations

Tags: equations

I need some help in this equation,

this is the equation I've written, but it shows error missing \endgroup inserted.

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq16}
B=\frac{\frac{\hat{v_{ro}}}{\hat{v_{\theta o}}}\bigl[ \frac{4\nu(n+1)}{b^2}r_o+2\omega r_o\frac{\hat{v_{ro}}}{\hat{v_{\theta o}}}\bigl\{1 $-$ \frac{2(n+1)}{(2n+1)}\hat{v_{ri}}-\nu(\frac{1}{r_i}+\frac{4(n+1)}{b^2}r_i) \bigr\}\bigr]}{\frac{2\nu(n+1)}{b^2}+\omega\frac{\hat{v_{ro}}}{\hat{v_{\theta o}}}}
\end{equation}
```

the problem I face here with $-$, if I remove math mode, * sign becomes the output for - sign.

The output file is attached in the figure, kindly help;[image]

Comment: Welcome! For sure you do not want `$` inside an equation environment.

Comment: just use `-` not `$-$` but also please always post a complete small document that shows the problem, that is much easier to debug than a fragment

Answer (score 1):

Some comments and suggestions:

- First and foremost, change `$-$` to just `-`.
- Be careful where you place the `\hat` accents.
- Please check if it should `ro` and `\theta o` or, rather, `r_0` and `\theta_0`.
- I suggest you use `\displaystyle` in both the main numerator and main denominator and increase the "fence" sizes from `\big` to `\bigg`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\frac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq16}
B=\ddfrac{\frac{\hat{v}_{r_0}}{\hat{v}_{\theta_0}}
\biggl[ \frac{4\nu(n+1)}{b^2}r_0+2\omega r_0
\frac{\hat{v}_{r_0}}{\hat{v}_{\theta_0}}
\biggl\{1 - \frac{2(n+1)}{(2n+1)}\hat{v}_{r_i}-\nu
\biggl(\frac{1}{r_i}+\frac{4(n+1)}{b^2}r_i\biggr) 
\biggr\} \biggr]}{\frac{2\nu(n+1)^{\mathstrut}}{b^2}
+\omega\frac{\hat{v}_{r_0}}{\hat{v}_{\theta_0}}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```